# Continuity of maps

Tags: general-topology, continuity

We consider this topological space $(\mathbb{R},\tau)$ where: $$\tau=\{G\subset \mathbb{R}, (\mathbb{R}\setminus G)~\text{countable}~\}\cup\{\emptyset\}$$

and we consider the identity map $$f: (\mathbb{R},\tau)\rightarrow (\mathbb{R},|.|)\\~~~ x~~~\mapsto ~~~ x$$

How to prove that $f$ is continuous using sequences at each $x_0$ but it is not continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If $(x_n)$ is any sequence that converges to $x_0$, then consider $C = \{x_n: x_n \neq x_0\}$, which is a countable set that does not contain $x_0$. So $X \setminus C$ is an open neighbourhood of $x_0$. By convergence for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ we have that for all $n \ge N$ : $x_n \in X \setminus C$. But this means that for all $n \ge N$, $x_n = x_0$ (otherwise $x_n$ would have been in $C$!).

So all sequences in $\tau$ are eventually constant, which settles the continuity by sequences (why?).

The identity is continuous iff the usual topology is a subset of $\tau$ (the inverse image of every usual open set should be in $\tau$). Show this is false, so $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: We suppose that $(x_n)$ is convergent to $x_0$ and we prove that $f(x_n)$ converge to $f(x_0)$ ? i know that if $(x_n)$ converge to $x_0$ then $\exists n_0, \forall n\geq n_0, x_n=x_0$ then as $f(x_n)=x_n$ and $f(x_0)=x_0$ we obtain the continuity ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou Yes, as eventually constant sequences are always convergent to the "eventual constant", in *any* topology

Comment: but please i don't understand how we say f is continuous at each $x_0$ but not continuous in $\mathbb{R}$? thank you

Comment: @Vrouvrou it's **not** continuous at $x_0$, it's *sequentially continuous*. This is weaker, as shown by this very example.

Comment: where i can find this ? difference between continuity and sequentially continuous ?

Comment: http://math.uga.edu/~pete/convergence.pdf is a nice start. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Definition_in_terms_of_limits_of_sequences has some remarks as well.